# Two Hubs must not share the same name

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr

I created asp.net mvc 5 application (call it "WebServices"), then i add my Hubs in a folder called "Hubs".
Now what happened is that SignalR (2.0.2) generate JavaScript proxies for hubs in environment:
1-in local machine.
2-when i publish to azure web role.
Now when i publish to azure website (.NET is 4.5 and websocket is opened),it didn't generate proxies.
Now i tried to add hubs to App_Code folder ,and it generate proxies ,but the build action of the hub classes are "Content",when i change it to Compile it raised this exception :

> Two Hubs must not share the same name. 'Webservices.App_Code.MyHub1,
>   App_Code.c9aucf2j, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Webservices.App_Code.MyHub1, Webservices,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' both share the
>   name 'MyHub1'.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Probably you accidentally loaded an old dll (or better the framework discovered one for you) which also contains a hub with the same name. In my case the framework loaded

```
MyHubsTest.dll (with myHub in it)
MyHubsTest.exe (with myHub in it)
```

You can check it in Debug -> Windows -> Modules

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I'm using ASP.NET 5, MVC6, and SignalR 2.2. To do this, I'm using the BuilderExtensions class detailed here:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/The-ASPNET-vNext-Real-Time-b1d27fe4

After a LONG debugging session, what ended up doing it was this part in my Startup.cs:

```
services.AddIdentity<ChirpUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
{
    config.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = Properties.Resource.AllowedUsernameCharacters;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ChirpContext>();
```

ChirpUser is the name of my User class, and ChirpContext is my DbContext class, but honestly I don't think that's the important bit.

The problem line is the call to Properties.Resources. I had defined a string of my allow username characters there, but when this line is included, I have the error you described. When I take the line out, the problem goes away.

I don't have a good explanation for this, but maybe it will fit your situation.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had converted my code into a web application and needed to move the hub class out of the app_code folder.

SignalR creates it's own virtual SignalR/Hubs folder.  Maybe try renaming your Hubs folder to _Code